# Is there a way to see a list of all the apps available on the app store?

Tags: itunes, ios, ios-appstore

I know that there are several ways to browse the App Store. You can see the featured apps, which I assume are featured by Apple staff. There's genius, which is based on your prir purchases. Then there are the Top Charts, which I guess are based on consumer choices. Categories allows you to see apps by category.

All of these are insanely great, but is there a way to just see an alphabetized list of all 500,000+ apps? Perhaps on iTunes on Mac OS X?

(Incidentally, it would take a hundred thousand iPhones to see all the apps at once.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not at my computer, so I can't test it in iTunes at the moment, but here's how to do it on iOS.

1. Go to the Featured section of the App Store.
2. Select the Release Date tab at the top.
3. Change sort method to Name.

Comment: I believe this is an iPad only feature, since I don't see a "Release Date" tab on my iPhone.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I'll try to find a way to do it in iTunes tomorrow.

Comment: HAve you had a chance to look?

Comment: @Moshe Not extensively, but yes, and I haven't found anything so far. Will let you know if I discover anything.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware Apple itself limits this to category. I think they have specifically not included this option to make browsing the AppStore a simpler process for not technical people, which is the bulk of their target market. Therefore even iTunes doesn't have an option to do this yet.

I use an App called [AppShopper](http://itunes.apple.com/za/app/appshopper/id387037496?mt=8) which allows you to search for specials, and also specify which categories you want to see. I haven't used it in a while but if I recall it does have an option to list all applications in all categories.